having trouble with Info and Describe error in Python?
I am an extreme beginner at Python in a tough project. I'm trying to load my excel data into Jupyter using pandas, and some functions work, but I'm having trouble getting df.info and df.describe to work.
(https://i.sstatic.net/VXxj8.png)
Thanks for any help!
The class appears to be a pandas dataframe, so I don't even really know where to begin debugging this. I've had to block out some stuff, but all info should be there.

This isn't how this site works. Please read How do I ask a good question?. Especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it says to not share screenshots and to share code. And how you want to make a minimal reproducible example (MRE). You don't need to share you actual data. Make a toy set of code that gives the same issue. You can share data that can be made into a pandas dataframe as code, too. Like here.

As to your issue. You also want to often Restart the Kernel when developing a Jupyter Notebook. You could have somehow clobbered the describe() attribute in your efforts to do something and not realized it. Your notebook has a lot of code we haven't seen run and steps you deleted. (Sometimes called the 'hidden state'.) Specifically the first cell we see is the 17th cell you executed and then a lot of things jump to around the 30s. What you shared doesn't look bad but we cannot tell about the hidden state. And you should always endeavor to eliminate the hidden state being an issue by ...

 restarting the kernel and runnning all cells. There's even a choice under the kernel menu to allow you to do redo this easily often. And you should make it a habit to do that. The more you do that the quicker you'll eliminate strange issues like this or catch something you deleted and didn't mean to delete and then you can add it back in while you still remember what you were doing. Finally, this is probably not reproducible and doesn't necessarily belong as a post on this forum as it is probably due to something you did, and so it would be unlikely to help others.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
